# How to control the number of messages that being emitted by Apache Kafka per a specific time?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am new to Apache Kafka and I am trying to configure Apache Kafka that it receives messages from the producer as much as possible but it only sends to the consumer configured number of messages per specific time.
In other words How to configure Apache Kafka to send only "50 messages for example" per "30 seconds"
to the consumer regardless of the number of the messages, and in the next 30 seconds it takes another 50 messages from the cashed messages and so on.

Comment: Why do you need that? In general this would be bad idea. In most cases it is best to send messages to output as fast as possible (to avoid data loss due to possible app crash).

Comment: I will use the consumed messages to communicate with a 3rd party provider with a limited number of requests per time.
So I am using Kafka as cashing to pull data from it periodically with the advance that Kafka solves the problem of pulling the same data twice if there are two instances of the consumer

Answer (score 2):

***If you have control over the consumer***

You could use [max.poll.records](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_max.poll.records) property to limit max number of records per `poll()` method call. And then you only need to ensure that `poll()` is called once in 30 seconds.

In general you can take a look at all available configuration properties [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#configuration).

***If you cannot control consumer***

Then the only option for you is to write messages as per your demand - write at most 50 messages in 30 seconds. There are no configuration options available. Only your application logic can achieve that.

***updated - how to control ensure call to poll***

The simplest way is to:

```
while (true) {
   consumer.poll()
   // .. do your stuff
   Thread.sleep(30000);
}
```

You can make things more complex with measuring time for processing (i.e. starting after `poll` call up to `Thread.sleep()` to not wait more then 30 seconds at all.

Comment: **I have control over the consumer** and my question is turned to be sample as **how to  ensure that `poll()` is called once in 30 seconds** while I am using spring-kafka ?

Comment: You didn't ask about that in your original question. See a comment to my answer: the `idleBetweenPolls` is for you. It does in the `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` exactly what @VladislavVarslavans shows in his last edit.

Comment: i can't use  "max.poll.records" in c# is there an alternative to this for c# https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/1451

Answer (score 2):

The problem that producer really doesn't send messages to the consumer. There is that persistent Kafka topic in between where producer places its messages. And it really doesn't care if there is any consumer on the other side. Same from the consumer perspective: it just subscribers for data from the topic and doesn't care if there is some producer on the other side. So, thinking about a back-pressure from the consumer down to producer where there is a messaging middle ware is wrong direction.

On the other hand it is not clear how those consumed messages may impact your third party service. The point is that Kafka consumer is single-threaded per partition. So, all the messages from one partition is going to be (must) processed one by one in the same thread. This way you cannot send more than one messages to your service: the next one can be sent only when the previous has been replied. So, think about it: how it is even possible in your consumer application to excess rate limit?

However if you have enough partitions and high concurrency on the consumer side, so you really may end up with several requests to your service in parallel from different threads. For this purpose I would suggest to take a look into a Rate Limiter pattern. This library provides a good implementation: https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/ratelimiter. It is much better to keep messages in the topic then try to limit producer somehow.

To conclude: even if the consumer side is not your project, it is better to discuss with that team how to improve their consumer. You did your part well: the producer sends messages to Kafka topic. What else you can do over here?

Comment: I am completely aware that there is a persistent Kafka topic and my question was how to control that the consumer call 'poll()' only 50 times in 30 seconds or call 'poll()' only once in 30 seconds but gets 50 messages as max

Comment: OK. See `max.poll.records` in the consumer configuration properties and `idleBetweenPolls` on the `idleBetweenPolls` of Spring Kafka: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#container-props. Your question in that part was not clear: Kafka doesn't send messages to the consumer. The consumer does a pulling logic. We also call it as a *delivery*. The "send" is exactly a producer part.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting use case and not sure why you need it, but two possible solutions: 1. To protect the cluster, you could use quotas, not for amount of messages but for bandwidth throughput: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_quotas . 2. If you need an exact amount of messages per time frame, you could put a buffering service (rate limiter) in between where you consume and pause, publishing messages to the consumed topic. Rate limiter could consume next 50 then pause until minute passes. This will increase space used on your cluster because of duplicated messages. You also need to be careful of how to pause the consumer, hearbeats need to be sent else you will rebalance your consumer continuously, ie you can't just sleep till next minute. This is obviously if you can't control the end consumer.